# how to debug REST in IntelliJ with TomEE?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am very new with IntelliJ and Java.

My service is very simple:

```
@Path("loyaltyMembers")
@ApplicationScoped
@Consumes(APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(APPLICATION_XML)
public class LoyaltyService {
    @POST
    @Path("status")
    public MemberStatusResp queryMemberStatus(MemberCard card) {
        MemberProfileResp retval = new MemberProfileResp();
        retval.setMemberName(new MemberName("michael","jackson"));
        return retval;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("profile")
    public MemberProfileResp queryMemberProfile(MemberCard card) {
        return null;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getHistory")
    public String getPointHistory() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

the project is setup using Maven and TomEE. 
I can compile properly and run the goal TomEE:run.

[image: using TomEE:run to start the service]

I can hit my endpoint getHistory properly and receive the response.

But when I try to Post to the status endpoint, it fails.

My question is, how can I enter the debug mode of IntelliJ?

I used the [Run]->[Edit Configurations] to create a Remote setting, it is like this:

[image: Remote Run Configuration]

but if I hit the debug mode using this configuration, I kept getting 
"Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8080)"

Does anyone know how to properly debug? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the maven command `tomee:run` in debug mode? Create a regular maven run configuration with this command and when running it, press the debug button.

Comment: I did try to open a terminal and run command line: mvn tomee:run. It can start the service, and I can hit the endpoints. and then I try to run in the remote debug mode, it still gave me "Error running remote: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8080): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed""

Comment: No, not a terminal. Create a "Maven Run/Debug Configuration" and then, to run it, instead of pressing the green play button (in the top-right bar), press the debug button.

Comment: hmm, I just tried. I created a Maven run configuration, and put "tomee:run" in the command line. Hit the debug button, it started the service, and I can hit the endpoint. but the IDE doesn't seem to be in the debug mode, I can't hit any breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install the Tomcat and TomEE Integration plugin in Intellij (`Settings > Plugins`).
2. Create a new Run configuration based on `TomEE Server`. Select local or remote depending on where you want to deploy your webservice.
3. Configure the configuration for your app (the Deployment tab should definitely be adapted).
4. If correctly configured, pressing the start button will compile, deploy and start your TomEE service. In this case, you can press the Debug button to start up the service in debug mode.

As a personal side-note: no need to use Maven run configurations. Instead learn to understand what needs to happen and how your IDE can help you with this. The above configuration will be ten times more productive than a Maven run configuration that is slow and poorly debuggable.

Comment: actually, I finally figured out how to debug it this morning. What I really should is to execute the goal: tomee:debug, which will start the server and listen to a different port: 5050, and then I create a remote run configuration to it. run debug, it works like magic!